# Orfeo Toolbox for QGIS not activating after trying several suggestions

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

There are several other threads on this topic and after trying the suggestions I am still stuck with Orfeo Toolbox not activating in QGIS.
Running 2.16 right now... any chance updating to the newest 2.16.3 version would help?
Screenshot of my Orfeo's activate [image: here].

Comment: I am thinking now I may not have the Orfeo apps placed in the correct folder. The values for some of the other apps are as follows, which one of these folders looks like a better spot for the Orfeo apps to be placed in ?     C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16\apps\grass\grass-7.0.4    
C:\Users\super\.qgis2\processing\rscripts    
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\bin

Comment: From the QGIS Help:  "If you use any of the installers that include OTB, such as OSGeo4W, there is no need for further configuration. Processing will detect the path automatically and will not show the corresponding configuration entries. Otherwise, fill the OTB applications folder and OTB command line tools folder parameters with the to the corresponding values for your installation." not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution
[image: Found a solution]
[Yoshimura Nobuhiko source: page 3 of 8](http://www.slideshare.net/YoshimuraNobuhiko/how-to-install-qgis-plugins)