# Splitting multilayer images

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, orfeo-toolbox

I have a multilayer image with hundreds of bands and I would like to extract them all automatically to single raster files, one file for every layer.

I'm looking for an automated process. I've got aware of the Orfeo Toolbox split image tool, but I don't manage to make it work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use gdal_translate and select the band with -b option. Make a script and walk through all the bands.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Orfeo Toolbox > Image Manipulation > Split Image`.  This splits an n-band multiband image into n images.  The output filename is a prefix and the channels (bands) are numbers accordingly e.g. if filename = 'myImage.tif' then the first band will be saved as 'myImage_0.tif' and the second 'myImage_1.tif' and so on.  See [here](https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2013/07/working-with-multispectral-bands-in-qgis.html) for a more detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having difficulties to install Orfeo Toolbox, the solution by @sirgeo [Orfeo Toolbox for QGIS not activating after trying several suggestions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215153/orfeo-toolbox-for-qgis-not-activating-after-trying-several-suggestions) worked for me, too.

In my case:

1. Download Orfeo Toolbox from https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/
2. Extract the zip file into C:\qgis_tools (Windows)
3. Set options for **Applications folder** and **Command line tools folder** (see below image)

[image]

NB. **Command line tools** was assigned to "bin" folder.

Once set-up, you can follow the instruction by @MappaGnosis.